# List all items less than average

Tags: excel, if-statement

Suppose we have  following data

```
prices

leptop  30
pc      29
table   10
house   15
car     25
train   32
pen     45
dog     33
cat     17
TV      8
```

I have calculated average of these prices avg==AVERAGE(D3:D12)  where  D3:D12 are price columns. Now I want to choose these items or  list items  which has  price less than average for example, I know there is function `if`, but how can I use it together to list  all data, which satisfies the  `if` condition?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073941.aspx#BMfilter_for_above_average_or_below_ave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to list the prices that are less than the average all in the same cell?
If you're just trying to indicate whether they are or not next to the column, you could use: =IF(D3 < AVERAGE($D$3:$D$12), "Less Than", "Greater or Equal")

Edit:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fahvc.png

Ok, to get the result you want (see image) then you need to use the following formulas (this assumes these formulas are in column F).

The first row in the column should be: =IF(B3 < AVERAGE($B$3:$B$6), A3, "") where B3 is the data and A3 is the name.

And all the other rows should be: =IF(B4 < AVERAGE($B$3:$B$6), IF(F3="", A4, F3 & ", " & A4), F3) where B4 is the data and A4 is the name.

Comment: i need names,not if they are less or  greater,just names for example average is 24.4,so all  items name which's price   is less then this number

Comment: Okay, there's a few ways to do this.  The easiest way is to use a VBA macro to loop through each cell, determine if it's less than the average, and then return the final result.

Comment: without macro is there such kind of  method?

Comment: @dato, all you need to to is to filter the data as "less than" and you will have a list of items which prices are smaller than average.

Comment: i will try it,please wait for a minute

Comment: if there is  multiple columns,then how to sort  seperately?

Comment: @AndreSilva, the OP would like to combine everything into 1 cell.  

Here you go:

In cell E3, use this formula: =IF(D3 < AVERAGE($D$3:$D$12), D3, "")
In cell E4, use this formula: =IF(D4 < AVERAGE($D$3:$D$12), E3 & ", " & D4, E3) and then drag it down to E12.  E12 will have the entire list of all items that are less than the average.

Comment: ok that what i need,i have list of names  and their courses,and also averages,what i need is following i need create three  names,like calc1,below which will be written all students name which's mark is less then average of calc1 ,the same for calc2 and  third course,did you get it

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/SRTfvJe.png  

Ok, to get the result you want (see image) then you need to use the following formulas (this assumes these formulas are in column F).  

The first row in the column should be: =IF(B3 < AVERAGE($B$3:$B$6), A3, "") where B3 is the data and A3 is the name.  

And all the other rows should be: =IF(B4 < AVERAGE($B$3:$B$6), IF(F3="", A4, F3 & ", " & A4), F3) where B4 is the data and A4 is the name.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could do with with `Advanced Filter`. Set-up your excel sheet as follows, and enter the formulas appropriately:

[image]

Then, go to `Advanced Filter`:

[image]

You will get:

[image]

Comment: thanks mariam,i am supprised it sounds georgian name,but about question,i have like this  student name,subject 1,subject 2,subject 3,how could i do seperately?

Comment: also what about advanced filter?

Comment: I am not sure you could do that simultaneously without VBA, or without manually repeating the `filter` action. Let me think a bit more about this. The main obstacle is that the filtering criteria would be different from one column to another (since the average might not be the same for each column).

Comment: The other thing you could do is rather write formulas. That would be easier to replicate for multiple columns. Would you want me to give you an example?

Comment: i have seperated  columns,i have different columns in different sheefts

Comment: Then I guess writing formulas that you could copy in all your sheets is your best bet. Let me know if you need an example

Answer (score 1):

In E3 and copied down:

```
=IF(D3<AVERAGE(D$3:D$12),C3,"")
```

will give a list (admittedly with spaces) if the names are in ColumnC. (Guessing that 'continue' does not mean the same cell.)

Answer (score 1):

Does a filter work for your needs? If I go to the "data" tab in Excel 2010, highlight the data, and click "Filter", I can filter on items "below average" in the price column.

Comment: but there is several column,imagin  students with  three subjects, and i want to filter seperately

Comment: Filter separately, like "filter multiple times to get multiple complete lists" or "filter on multiple items, so that only items matching ALL the filters are shown in a single list"? You can certainly apply multiple filters at the same time for the latter.